# An Active directory domain controller could not be contacted

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

After creating an Active Directory domain controller I tried to add client computers to the domain but I kept hitting a snag.

> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain x.x.com:
>   The error was: DNS name does not exist.
>       (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>       The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.x.x.com

After encountering this I made sure the client computer was using the preferred domain name of the server and the IP-address. 
Both computers were able to ping one another successfully.

After this I tried again and then hit another snag

> An active directory domain controller for the domain zedvance.com could not be contacted

upon clicking the details i saw this

> The error was: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I've been stuck on this for quite a while now.

Comment: Is your DC also a DNS Server? Check if your DNS SRV Resource Records are correct/exist. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816587/en

Comment: Can you ping the domain name itself from the client?  ie. `ping x.x.com` and get a response from the domain controller?

Comment: Can you run dcdiag on the domain controller?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dcdiag

Answer (score 1):

First check that the DNS record in the error does in fact exist. If not:

1. Make sure the DC is using itself as its primary DNS server.
2. Restart the netlogon service on the DC to re-register the SRV records.

Check the records now exist. If they do, ensure your client is using the DC as its primary DNS server and try to join again (but first run 'ipconfig /flushdns' to clear your DNS cache on the client)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure the ip configurations of your client machine, make it the same as DC, instead of the ip address. Then try ping the ip address of your server, if it is successful, then join the domain. Or, you can turn off the firewall of server and your client machine, then try again.

Answer (score -1):

Point the PCs to the DC's DNS IP.
If you tried that already, try adding the IP address of your DC as a WINS server.